# Как задать имя таблицы для модели в PHPixie?

Tags: php, phpixie

> Внимание! Этот вопрос является переводом вопроса: [How can I specify
>   the database table name for a model in
>   PHPixie?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46022927/5752652)

Получаю следующую ошибку

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'phpixie.persons' doesn't exist

когда делаю запрос к таблице 'people':

```
public function getPerson($person_id)
{
    return $this->components()->orm()->query('person')
        ->where('id', $person_id)
        ->findOne();
}
```

Из [документации](https://phpixie.com/components/orm.html):

> By default ORM assumes that the table name is the plural of the name
>   of the model, and that the name of the primary key is ‘id’.

Можно ли как-то переопределить имя таблицы на собственное?

PS Или задать список исключений как в [EnglishPluralizationService](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Data.Entity.Design/System/Data/Entity/Design/PluralizationService/EnglishPluralizationService.cs):

> {"child", "children"} {"corpus","corpora"} {"person", "people"}

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46022927/how-can-i-specify-the-database-table-name-for-a-model-in-phpixie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В зависимости от версии PHPixie есть следующие способы:

#### `2.x`

В предположении что у вас уже есть модель `Person` model вы можете просто указать имя таблицы в поле `$table`:

```
class Person extends \PHPixie\ORM\Model
{
     public $table = 'person';
}
```

См. в документации:

- https://phpixie.com/2.x/orm.html

#### `3.x`

Вы можете переопределить значение по умолчанию в конфигурационном файле:

```
<?php
// bundles/app/assets/config/orm.php

return array(
    'models' => array(
        'person' => array(
            'table'=> 'persons',
        ),
    );
);
```

См. в документации:

- https://phpixie.com/components/orm.html#configuration